# Populate class from database

Tags: c#, class

Here is the method so far.

```
public static void FillUserListClass()
{    
    List<User> UserList = new List<User>();
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strAccessConn);
    string query = "SELECT ControlNumber, UserName FROM Log WHERE Log.EndStatus in ('Needs Review', 'Check Search', 'Vision Delivery', 'CA Review', '1TSI To Be Delivered');";

    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        adapter.Fill(dt);

        for (int ctr = 1; ctr <= dt.Rows.Count; ctr++)
        {
            UserList.UserName.Add(dt.Columns["UserName"].ToString());
            UserList.ControlNumber.Add(Convert.ToInt32(dt.Columns["ControlNumber"]));
        }
    }
    catch (OleDbException ex)
    {}
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }               
}
```

What i want to do is grab the ControlNumber & UserName using my query, and make a unique class for each UserName. Each User Class

```
class User
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public List<Int32> ControlNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Will contain the User's Name (username) and a list of control numbers (controlNumbers) that i pull using my query.

Comment: do you want to create classes at runtime? isn't it?

Comment: What is your `Question` here...?

Comment: I suppose i didn't ask a question. But, i'm just trying to see if I'm on the right path to do what I want to do. I'm new to C# and it seems like i am..but then again, i could be pitching to the wrong team

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also do this easily with LINQ and it's easier to read and more concise:

```
var users = from c in dt.AsEnumerable()
            group c by c.Field<string>("UserName") into gr
            select new  User { Username=  gr.Key ,
                                ControlNumbers = (from x in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                                  where x.Field<string>("UserName") == gr.Key 
                                                  select x.Field<int>("ControlNumber")).ToList() };
```

## Update:

```
List<User> userList = (from c in dt.AsEnumerable()
                group c by c.Field<string>("UserName") into gr
                select 
                new User { 
                           Username=  gr.Key ,
                           ControlNumbers = 
                           (from x in dt.AsEnumerable()
                           where x.Field<string>("UserName") == gr.Key 
                           select x.Field<int>("ControlNumber")).ToList() 
                          }
                        ).ToList();
```

So basically, you are taking your data table, grouping by UserName and using this list of unique user names to query the data table once again, to read all Control Numbers pertaining to the current UserName.

Comment: I'm getting "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>'" at the .ToList() part....shouldn't this be .ToList<?>

Comment: @MaylorTaylor I edited the answer. You were getting the exception because your User class definition has `List<int>` for ControlNumber but my example was building a `List<string>`, hence the `ClassCastException`. I changed the code to `select x.Field<int>("ControlNumber")` and that ought to fix it.

Comment: Ok, this LINQ stuff is making more sense now...but how would populate my User class (which contains 'string UserName' and 'list<int32> ControlNumber') with this information?

Comment: Since this is the first piece of LINQ i've had in my code ever. I'm quite confused on how it all works still. It seems the last thing you posted (under Update) it's doing the same thing as the previous one...the only difference is what you are setting it to. The second one is a List called userList...right?

Comment: @MaylorTaylor correct. The only change I made there was putting the whole thing between `()` and then calling `ToList()`. The reason for this is that without the last `ToList()` you would have gotten back an `IEnumerable<User>` instead of a `List<User>`, which is what you wanted to get back.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Dictionary` like this:

```
public static void FillUserListClass()
{
    Dictionary<string, User> UserList = new Dictionary<string, User>();
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strAccessConn);
    string query = "SELECT ControlNumber, UserName FROM Log WHERE Log.EndStatus in ('Needs Review', 'Check Search', 'Vision Delivery', 'CA Review', '1TSI To Be Delivered');";

    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        adapter.Fill(dt);

        for (int ctr = 1; ctr <= dt.Rows.Count; ctr++)
        {
            var row = dt.Rows[ctr];
            var userName = row["UserName"].ToString();
            if (!UserList.ContainsKey(userName))
            {
                UserList.Add(userName, new User()
                {
                    UserName = userName,
                    ControlNumber = new List<int>()
                });
            }
            UserList[userName].ControlNumber.Add((int)row["ControlNumber"]);
        }
    }
    catch (OleDbException ex)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```